# Alternatives to Dolby Home Theater application?

Tags: audio, acer-aspire

Dolby Home Theater is an application which is installed by default on many Acer laptops. It improves sound using an equalizer, AND has other enhancers such as Volume Leveler, Dialog Enhancer and surround visualizer. It enhances all output audio, as opposed to for just one application.

My problem is that this, like many Acer applications, crashes without any warning so I am often not using it, or having to manually open it many times. Is there an alternative to this poorly developed software?

Answer (score 1):

[SRS Audio Essentials](http://www.dts.com/audioessentials/) does much of the same.

From PCWorld:

> SRS Audio Essentials Enhances Sound to Awesome (but Addictive) Standards

Another option: [DFX](http://www.fxsound.com/)